# How to draw a corner at the end of text

Tags: graphics, framed

I would like to draw my logo with latex. The logo is very simple. It is a text, followed by a corner, which started at the bottom line.

[image: Example logo]

The size of the corner should change according to the font size of the text.

With best

Torsten

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I've inserted your image. It might help you to show what you have got so far, or what you have tried, and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: Do you want to put this logo in the footer or at the bottom of the `body`of the page (i.e. the very last line of the body)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is a logo, I suggest you use `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {The end};
\draw[thick,red] (a.east) -- (a.north east) -- +(-2ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `\scalebox` allows you to make the text & mark any size

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\endmark{\def\stackalignment{r}\stackon[0pt]{%
  \kern1.5pt\rule{.75pt}{2.1ex}}{\llap{\rule{2.1ex+.75pt}{.75pt}}}}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{3}{\scshape The end\endmark}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fwiw, there is a unicode mathematical character, which may be useful here; the decl in unicode-math is: `\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0231D}{\urcorner }{\mathclose}{upper right corner}%`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a) {The End};
\draw[very thick,black] (a.base east) -- (a.north east) -- +(-3ex,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot. Using a.base helps to bring the line on the baseline.